# Inconsistent ISO 8601 Formatting in Spring-Boot Rest Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, swagger

We are building a REST service as a Spring-Boot app, with “Jackson” for the JSON conversion, and “Swagger V.3” for the documentation. My issue is that ﻿ISO 8601 allows both ﻿±hh:mm AND ﻿±hhmm as valid Timezone format, which results in inconsistencies.

When defining a REST GET call, that takes a date with time (lastModified in this case), we have but one choice(?), to define the Date format as in Swagger:

```
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter(description="...",required=false)
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam(value="lastModified",required=false)
@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
Date lastModified
```

A date parameter of this form will be accepted:

`2020-04-15T00:00:00.000%2b00:00`

But this form (no : in the timezone) will cause an error:

`2020-04-15T00:00:00.000%2b0000`

The call *response* contains a date, which will be used as input for the next API call (lastModified value for next search). If I annotate it like this:

`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")`

The JSON date looks like this (no : in the timezone):

`2020-11-12T11:35:34.006+0000`

And the Swagger “example” looks like this:

`2020-11-16T10:55:01.375Z`

If I annotate it like this:

`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")`

The JSON date looks like this:

`2020-11-12T11:35:34.006Z`

And the Swagger “example” looks like this:

`2020-11-16T10:50:04.874Z`

The client complained that is they need “:” in the query parameter, it should be in the JSON output too (or, it should be in neither). AFAIK, I have to use DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME for the query parameter, which means it must have “:” in the timezone.

So, how do I convince Jackson to put a “:” in the timezone output, and Swagger to use the ":" in it's example?

I have tried formatting the (result) date myself, and returning it as String instead, but then the Swagger documentation just specifies it as being a string, and not a date.

Comment: Have you tried `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSETT_DATE_TIME` or `.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`?

Comment: `The JSON date looks like this:

2020-11-12T11:35:34.006Z

And the Swagger “example” looks like this:

2020-11-16T10:50:04.874Z` - which of these two is the correct date-time?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Those are examples of "format", not actual values. Assuming I cannot change the "Parameter Format" (+00:00), then I don't want "Z" in either the JSON output, nor in the Swagger example. "Correct" for me is simply "the same format everywhere".

Comment: @daniu Assuming you mean java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter, I don't see how/where I could use it to solve my problem. DateTimeFormatter is an actual formatter, not an annotation. AFAIK, I can neither use it in the *specification* of my Rest call parameter, nor can I tell JSON to use it to format my result date. As I said in the last sentence, formating the date "myself" is not an option, bc Swagger then "documents" it as a simple String.